# ¿Cómo calcular límites no exactos de un intervalo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda

En un intervalo cuyo límite inferior es 0 y su límite superios 100, queremos crear 10 intervalos cuyos límites sean inexactos, por ejemplo 0-10, 11-20, etc.

Lo intento de ésta manera.

```
def calcular_rangos_edad_inexacto(limite_inferior, limite_superior, num_rangos):
    rango_total = limite_superior - limite_inferior
    amplitud_porcentaje = 100.0 / num_rangos
    rango_edad = []
    for i in range(num_rangos):
        lim_inf_rango = limite_inferior + (i * amplitud_porcentaje / 100.0) * rango_total
        lim_sup_rango = limite_inferior + ((i + 1) * amplitud_porcentaje / 100.0) * rango_total
        lim_inf_rango_inexacto = lim_inf_rango + (amplitud_porcentaje / 200.0) * rango_total
        lim_sup_rango_inexacto = lim_sup_rango - (amplitud_porcentaje / 200.0) * rango_total
        rango_edad.append(f"{lim_inf_rango_inexacto:.1f}-{lim_sup_rango_inexacto:.1f}")
    return rango_edad

limite_superior = 100
limite_inferior = 0
num_rangos = 10
rangos = rango_inexacto(limite_inferior, limite_superior, num_rangos)
rangos
```

En esta función, primero calculamos la amplitud de cada rango como un porcentaje del rango total de edad. Luego, utilizamos dos fórmulas diferentes para calcular los límites inferior y superior de cada rango. Para el límite inferior, añadimos la mitad de la amplitud del rango al límite inferior del rango. Para el límite superior, restamos la mitad de la amplitud del rango del límite superior del rango.

En el bucle for, iteramos a través de cada rango y creamos una cadena que representa el rango de edad inexacto utilizando la cadena de formato "{:.1f}-{:.1f}" para mostrar un solo decimal en los límites de los rangos de edad.

Me devuelve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo cual no es lo que deséo. ¿uál es el error?. Agradeceré ayuda?.

Comment: El código tiene errores de sintaxis. Una vez corregido, el código no arroja ningún resultado.

Comment: El ejemplo tiene un número impar de elementos (101). No puedes dividirlo en 10 grupos pues 101 es un número primo.

Comment: Hola efueyo, a que te refieres con "límites inexactos"?, a que no necesariamente tengan el mismo tamaño?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede que se trate de un caso de sobre-ingeniería o puede que yo no esté entendiendo la pregunta. Aquí mi intento:

```py
limite_superior = 100
limite_inferior = 0
num_rangos = 10
rangos = [f'{i}-{i+num_rangos-1}'for i in range(limite_inferior+1,limite_superior,num_rangos)]
print(rangos)
```

```
['1-10',
 '11-20',
 '21-30',
 '31-40',
 '41-50',
 '51-60',
 '61-70',
 '71-80',
 '81-90',
 '91-100']
```

El primero es un caso especial, porque es un rango con un año más, así que puede ser tratado aparte.

```py
rangos =[f'0-{num_rangos}']+[f'{i}-{i+num_rangos-1}'for i in range(limite_inferior+num_rangos+1,limite_superior,num_rangos)]
print(rangos)
```

```
['0-10',
 '11-20',
 '21-30',
 '31-40',
 '41-50',
 '51-60',
 '61-70',
 '71-80',
 '81-90',
 '91-100']
```

Comment: No entiendo cuál es la diferencia entre los dos, que me tratas de decir.

Comment: Gracias Luciano. Tengo otra duda. En el caso de límites con, por ejemplo,  dos decimales, ¿También nos servirá ésta sentencia?.

Comment: La segunda, incluye el 0, lo cuál es lo correcto para que todos los valores de la muestra puedan ser incluidos en una de las clases.

Comment: la diferencia con el primer rango es que tiene 11 elementos (de 0 a 10, inclusive), mientras que los demás tiene 10 elementos (por ejemplo de 11 a 20, inclusive). Si son períodos de tiempo (como años) entonces el primer período es más largo.

Comment: Esta solución no funciona con decimales, porque range no soporta float.

Answer (score 1):

Para límites no exactos, he encontrado ésta solución.

```
# Límites inexactos.
# A DataFrame is created with the columns LimInf and LimSup
intervalos_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "LimInf": np.arange(min_value, min_value + sturges_interval_num * interval_size, interval_size),
    "LimSup": np.arange(min_value + interval_size - 1, min_value + sturges_interval_num * interval_size, interval_size)
})

# print intervals
print(intervalos_df)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este código crea un DataFrame llamado **intervalos** que contiene dos columnas llamadas **LimInf** y **LimSup**.

La columna **LimInf** se crea utilizando la función arange de NumPy, que genera una secuencia de números espaciados uniformemente entre dos valores. En este caso, los valores utilizados son **min_value** (que se supone que es el valor mínimo de los datos) y **min_value + sturges_interval_num * interval_size**, que es el valor máximo de los datos. **sturges_interval_num** es el número de intervalos que se desea crear y **interval_size** es el tamaño de cada intervalo.

La columna **LimSup** se crea de manera similar, utilizando la misma secuencia de valores que la columna **LimInf**, pero desplazando cada valor hacia la derecha en un tamaño de intervalo y restando 1. Esto se hace para asegurarse de que los intervalos no se solapen.